# Mi app de flutter no funciona en android

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Estoy enfrentando un problema. Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Flutter y actualmente utilizamos la versión 2.12.0-4.1.pre. Recientemente, hemos experimentado un inconveniente: al enviar el archivo APK a nuestro cliente y descargarlo en su dispositivo Samsung Ultra S22, aparece una alerta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el emulador, la aplicación funciona perfectamente sin ningún problema; sin embargo, en dispositivos reales, la aplicación no funciona debido a problemas de compatibilidad. ¿Qué acciones puedo tomar para resolver esto? (SOLO ME PASA EN ANDROID)

Este es mi flutter doctor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, te sugiero agregar el AndroidManifest.xml y el app/build.gradle de tu anterior y actual versión, ahí encontraras el problema que no permite instalar tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Tu aplicación no es compatible con tu dispositivo ya que algún requerimiento ha cambiado, puede ser el nivel de API soportado por la aplicación, tamaños de tamaño especifico o incluso alguna declaración de Hardware en el [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=es-419) el cual no es soportado por tu dispositivo.

Por ejemplo si agregaste alguna caracteristica de Hardware, en caso de que no sea requisito esencial para el funcionamiento de tu aplicación, te sugiero definir el atributo `android:required` como `"false"`, para que los dispositivos que no cuenten con determinado Hardware puedan instalar tu aplicación:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
                  android:required="false" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

incluso si haces uso del NDK, asegura que este sea soportado por las mismas architecturas que tu versión anterior de la aplicación:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"/*, "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"*/
}
```